# Bash sqlite3: Error: too many options

Tags: bash, sqlite

I'm trying to fetch values from a mysql table and write them to sqlite3 using bash.
My script works when there's no space in the mysql row values that I fetch. Looks like some escaping problem, but I don't know much bash, and I tried quotes and curly braces around my variable (`$output_line` below) but it still doesn't work.

Here's what I have currently:

```
#!/bin/bash

first_line=0
while read -r output_line; do
    if [ $first_line -eq 0 ]
    then
        ((first_line++))
        continue
    fi
    sqlite3 /var/lib/asterisk/mydb.sqlite3 "update mydb set value='"$output_line"' where key='xxx/"$first_line"/xxx';"
    ((first_line++))
done < <(mysql -u root -p**** -hlocalhost MYDB -e "SELECT name FROM MYTABLE")
```

The error I get is when `$output_line` in the sqlite query has a space.
How can I fix this?

Comment: In your SQL query, instead of `"...='"$var"'..."`, use `"...='$var'..."` ; there's no reason to break the string, and that's most likely what causes your error. Also the whole thing reeks of SQL injection, I hope your sources are trusted

Comment: Expansion on the last part of my previous comment : if one of the `name` returned by the `SELECT name FROM MYTABLE` is `'; DROP TABLE MYTABLE; --` well congrats, the whole system just blown itself up. So maybe you can say you trust the content of `MYTABLE` not to have anything shabby like that. But you know what would be more simple? to avoid SQL Injection by using the standard process in place, like prepared statements that should definitely be usable with your `sqlite3` command. Edit : I guess `MYTABLE` only exists on the mysql database and not on the sqlite one, so my example isn't so good

Comment: Thanks @Aaron. That solved my problem. Could you please post it as an answer, so I can accept it?

Answer (score 1, accepted):

Alright so I haven't any sqlite3 environment handy so I couldn't test anything, but from what I read

- the `sqlite3` CLI can't use prepared statements
- but a [`quote(x)` method](https://sqlite.org/lang_corefunc.html#quote) is available as another way to mitigate SQL Injection

You should test the following code :

```
#!/bin/bash

line_number=0
while read -r output_line; do
    sqlite3 /var/lib/asterisk/mydb.sqlite3 "update mydb set value=quote('$output_line') where key=quote('xxx/$first_line/xxx');"
    ((line_number++))
done < <( mysql -u root -p**** -hlocalhost MYDB -e "SELECT name FROM MYTABLE" | tail -n+2 )
```

Comment: Thank you for the `quote(x)` method, I will give that a try.